Mollifiers make partition of unity
I am working through Evan's PDE book and I found these nice exercises. Problem 5 is not that hard. I am having trouble with problem 6:


Let $U$ and $V$ be open sets with $V \subset \subset U$. Show there exists a smooth function $\xi$ such that $\xi\equiv 1$ on $V$, $\xi=0$ in $\partial U$.


I was able to solve this using mollifiers as suggested by Evans. If anyone is interested here is my take on problem 5:
Because of compactness of $\overline{V}\subset U$, we may take a finite number of closed balls $B[x_i,r]$ contained in $U$ covering $\overline{V}$. We refer to the  union of $B(x_i,r)$ as $W_1$. By construction, $\overline{W_1}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^n\overline{ B(x_i,r_i)}\subset U$. We repeat the process to build compact sets contained in each other:
$$V\subset \overline{V} \subset W_1 \subset \overline{W_1}\subset W_2 \subset \overline{W_2}\subset U $$
We claim that $d(\overline{W_1},\partial W_2)=\alpha>0$. If this weren't the case, we would find sequences $w_n^1\in \overline{W_1}$ and $w_n^2\in \partial W_2$ such that $d(w_n^2,w_n^2)\rightarrow 0$. By taking subsequences which converge (by sequential compactness), we find that $\emptyset\not=\partial W_2\cap \overline{W_1}\subseteq W_2\cap \partial W_2$. However, $W_2$ is open, so it cannot have any boundary point.
By symmetry, one can prove that $d(\overline{V},\partial W_1)=\alpha'>0$. Now we fix $\varepsilon<\min\{\alpha/2,\alpha'\}$. In this case, once we consider $\xi =\eta_\varepsilon *\chi_{W_1}$ we have that:
$$\xi(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)\chi_{W_1}(y)dy=\int_{W_1\cap B(x,\varepsilon)} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)dy$$
If $x\in V$, then  $ B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq W_1$ and $\xi(x)=1$. Indeed, if this weren't the case, there would be $z\in B(x,\varepsilon)\cap W_1^C$. By elementary topology, $W_1^C=\partial W_1\cup \overline{W_1}^C$. If $z\in \partial W_1$, this is absurd as it would imply $\alpha'=d(\overline{V}, \partial W')\leq d(x,z)< \varepsilon$. Thus, $z$ must be in $\overline{W_1}^C$ and we have a non trivial cision of the ball which is equaly absurd. Thus, we need $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq W_1$ and $\xi(x)=1$.
If $x\in \partial U$, then $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap W_1=\emptyset $ and we have $\xi(x)=0$. Indeed, if this weren't the case, there would be $z\in B(x,\varepsilon)\cap W_1 $. Taking the line $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ connecting $x$ to $z$, we find points in both $W_2$ and $W_2^C$, (namely $x\in \partial U\subseteq W_2^C$ and $z\in W_1\subseteq W_2$). Because $[0,1]$ is connected and also  $g^{-1}(\overline{W_2}^C)\dot{\cup}g^{-1}(W_2)\dot{\cup}g^{-1}(\partial W_2)$, we must have a point $\tilde{x}$ in $\partial W_2\cap B(x,\varepsilon)$ (otherwise there would be a nontrivial partition by open sets of $[0,1]$). However the existence of $\tilde{x}$ is also absurd, as it would imply that $0<\alpha=d(\overline{W_1},\partial W_1)\leq d(z,\tilde{x})\leq d(z,x)+d(x,\tilde{x})<2\varepsilon$. Thus, $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap W_1=\emptyset$ and $\xi(x)=0$. We observe that the same proof that $\xi|_{\partial U}=0$ applies for $\xi|_{W_2^C}$. Thus in a sense we have that $\xi=0$ "near" $\partial U$ aswell.
I tried to use this result to work on the following:


Assume that $U$ is bounded and $U\subset \subset \cup_{i=1}^N V_i$ where the $V_i$ are open. Prove there are $0 \leq \xi_i\leq 1$ such that $\text{spt}(\xi_i )\subseteq V_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N \xi_i=1$.


I have an idea of how to attack this 6th problem, but I am having trouble with smoothness...
Indeed, question6 has been asked before, but I do not see how the answer works through the $C^\infty $ issue.
Here is what I have done so far:
Firstly, we may assume that $U$ is open. If it is not, we define $U'=\{x| d(x,U)<\varepsilon\}$ where $\varepsilon$ is small enough for $\{x| d(x,U)\leq\varepsilon  \}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^N V_i$. In this case the closure of $U'$ is still compact and contained in $\cup_{i=1}^NV_i$ and we may work with $U'$ which satisfies $U\subset\subset U'\subset\subset\cup_{i=1}^N V_i$.
Because $\overline{U}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^N V_i$ is compact, this means that for each $x\in \overline{U}$, there is a corresponding $V_{i(x)}$ and a radius small enough such that $B(x,r_{x})\subset \overline{B(x,r_{x})}\subseteq V_{i(x)}$. We may take a finite number of these, namely $x_1,...,x_M$ to cover $\overline{U}$ and we partition them acording to which $V_i$ they belong to, namely $W_i=\cup_{i(x_j)=i}B(x_j,r_{x_j})$. In this case, we have that
$$U\subset \overline{U}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^N W_i\subseteq \overline{\cup_{i=1}^N W_i}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^M\overline{B(x_i,r_{x_i})} \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^N V_i$$
In particular, we have that $U\cap W_i\subset \overline{U\cap W_i}\subset \overline{U}\cap \overline{W_i}\subset V_i $. Because of our Fifth Problem, we have that there exists $\hat{\xi}_i$ which is $1$ on $U\cap W_i$ and $0$ near $\partial V_i$.  We define:
$$\xi_i(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{\hat{\xi}_i(x)}{\sum_{j=1}^n\hat{\xi}_j(x)} \:\text{if there is $j\not=i$ with $\hat{\xi_j}\not=0$}\\
\hat{\xi_i}(x) \:\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
I could probably argue that the $\xi_i$ are continuous but I am a long way from proving they are $C^\infty$.

On the boundary of $\cup_{j\not=i}\hat{\xi_j}(\mathbb{R}\setminus {0})$ things get nasty looking...

I am still interested in an answer that succesfully employs exercise $5$.
Maybe the best way is just to ignore it. Here is how one can do it:
Firstly, we may assume that $U$ is open. If it is not, we define $U'=\{x| d(x,U)<\varepsilon\}$ where $\varepsilon$ is small enough for $\{x| d(x,U)\leq\varepsilon  \}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^N V_i$. In this case the closure of $U'$ is still compact and contained in $\cup_{i=1}^NV_i$ and we may work with $U'$ which satisfies $U\subset\subset U'\subset\subset\cup_{i=1}^N V_i$. There is plenty to be checked:

There exists this $\varepsilon>0$:
We need $d(U,( \cup_{i=1}^N V_i)^C)=\alpha>0$. Otherwise, there is a sequence of points such that $d(u_n, v_n)\rightarrow 0$. Because $u_n\in U\subseteq \overline{U}$ which is compact, we may take a convergent subsequence. For $n$ large enough, $v_n\in ( \cup_{i=1}^N V_i)^C\cap B[0,N+1]$ where $U\subseteq B[0,N]$. Indeed, $d(v_n,0)\leq d(v_n,u_n)+d(u_n,0)\leq 1+ N  $. Hence, it is actually in a compact set as well and we may take a convergent sub sequence. But then, we have $\emptyset\not= \overline{U}\cap ( \cup_{i=1}^N V_i)^C\subseteq (\cup_{i=1}^N V_i) \cap (\cup_{i=1}^N V_i)^C=\emptyset $, which is absurd . We may define $\varepsilon>0$ to be $\alpha/2$. Indeed, in this case $\{x| d(x,U)\leq \varepsilon\}$ has no point in  $(\cup_{i=1}^N V_i)^C$. If it did, $\alpha <d(U,(\cup_{i=1}^N V_i)^C)\leq d(x,U)<\alpha/2$, which is absurd.

$U\subset \subset  U'\subset\subset \cup_{i=1}^N V_i$:
By our definition of $U'$, it is clear that:
$$U\subseteq \overline{U}\subseteq \{x | d(x,U)\leq \varepsilon/2\}\subseteq U'\subseteq \overline{U'}\subseteq \{x| d(x,U)\leq \varepsilon\}\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^n V_i$$


Once we have this, we may work with our usual partitions of unity from our study of manifolds, but they are countable. That is, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \hat{\xi_i} (x)=1$,  for $x\in U'$, $\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_i})\subseteq V_{j_i}$ and $0 \leq \hat{\xi_i}\leq 1$. By the proof of this fact, we actually know there is a neighborhood which intersects only finitely many $\text{spt}(\xi_i)$. With this in mind, we could define:
$$\xi_i(x)=\sum_{\text{spt}{\hat{\xi_j}}\subset V_i}\hat{\xi}_j(x)\quad i=1,..,N$$
Locally, there is a neighborhood with only finitely many $\hat{\xi}_j$ non zero, so locally this sum is a finite combination of $C^\infty$ functions, hence $C^\infty$, as differentiability is a local property.

$0 \leq \xi_i(x)\leq 1$
We ressort to the construction of the $\hat{\xi_j}$. When they are non zero, they are given explicitly as the mean over certain smooth functions, that is, $\hat{\xi_j}=\frac{\zeta_i}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \zeta_i} $. If we take a subset, we are still dividing by the whole, namely, $\xi_i(x)=\frac{\sum_{s\in  S\subset \mathbb{N}}\zeta_s}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \zeta_i}  $, so we have $0 \leq \xi_i\leq 1 $

$\text{spt}({\xi_i})\subseteq V_{i}$
This is the trickiest bit. We need to prove $\text{spt}(\xi_i)\subseteq \cup_{\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})\subseteq V_i}\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})$. This is enough because it implies that $\text{spt}(\xi_i)\subset V_i$. To prove it, we first notice that $A=\{x|\xi_i(x)\not=0\}\subseteq \cup_{\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})\subseteq V_i}\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})$. If we prove the union is closed, then we are done as the support is the closure of $A$. We know so far it  suffices to prove $\cup_{\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})\subseteq V_i}\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})$ is closed. Take  $x\in \cap_{\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})\subseteq V_i} \text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j} )^C$. Every $x$ has a neihborhood that intercepts only finitely many $\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})$. Let $V$ be this neighborhood. In particular it intersepts finitely many $\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})\subset V_i$ which we index by $1,..,K$. But then we have built an open neighborhood as $x\in \cap_{j=1}^K V\setminus \text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})\subseteq \cap_{\text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j})\subseteq V_i} \text{spt}(\hat{\xi_j} )^C$ and we are done!

$\sum_{i=1}^N \xi_i(x)=1$ in $U'$.
We have only grouped the terms in the original partition of unity and this is allowed because positive terms are commutatively convergent. (Actually the sum is locally finite, so no Tonelli is needed.)


Of course what we have actually done is find a partition of $U'$. But this is all we need as $U\subseteq U'$.
